# WPF DataGrid ClipboardBinding Multibinding possible?

Tags: wpf, multibinding

is there a solution to bind multiple properties to my ClipboardBinding.
I tried the following code but this didnt work:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Characteristic.Area.Name.ActualTranslation" MinWidth="120" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Characteristic.Area.Name.ActualTranslation}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="  "></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AreaItem.Value}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc Area}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.ClipboardContentBinding>
        <!-- TODO: ClipboardBinding Area -->
        <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="Characteristic.Area.Name.ActualTranslation" />
            <Binding Path="AreaItem.Value" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.ClipboardContentBinding>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

i'd appreciate adivce for a workaround too.
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use converter ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)).

```
class StringFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format(parameter.ToString(), values);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.ClipboardContentBinding>      
    <MultiBinding  
        ConverterParameter=" {0} {1}"
        Converter="{StaticResource conString}">
        <Binding Path="Characteristic.Area.Name.ActualTranslation" />
        <Binding Path="AreaItem.Value" />
    </MultiBinding>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.ClipboardContentBinding>
```

Comment: thanks :) I've added the following line to ensure that the converter doesnt crash if a bindingproperty is optional.. `values = values.Where(x => x != null && x != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue).
                        Union(values.Where(x => x == null || x == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue).Select(x => "")).ToArray();`